# Exception executing isMaster command on in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am attempting to write to mongodb from an application deployed in JBOSS, this is what I get, is there anything I need to do in mongodb? it seems like a concurrency issue from discussions in forums.

```
14:00:07,083 WARNING [com.mongodb.tcp] (Camel (camel-2) thread #3 - JmsConsumer[barTopic]) Exception executing isMaster command on /127.0.0.1:27017: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:203) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:539) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:600) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:233) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:205) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:100) [mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar:]
        at com.magick.magicktrader.BarServiceBean.addBarToMongoDB(BarServiceBean.java:196) [magicktrader.jar:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.magick.magicktrader.BarServiceBean.getBar(BarServiceBean.java:40) [magicktrader.jar:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_10]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_10]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_10]
```

**The method call**

```
    MongoURI uri = null;
        uri = new MongoURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");

        try{
    mongo = new Mongo(uri);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
    //prop.getProperty("database")
    db = mongo.getDB("charts");
    db.requestStart();
    //prop.getProperty("collection")
    dbCollection = db.getCollection("bars");


    /**
     * Bar Structure - attributes
     * 
     * symbol,low,high
     * open,close,time
     * volume;
     **/
    for (Bar bar : barList) {
        document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("symbol", bar.getSymbol());
        document.put("low", bar.getLow());
        document.put("high", bar.getHigh());
        document.put("open", bar.getOpen());
        document.put("close", bar.getClose());
        document.put("time", bar.getTime());
        document.put("volume", bar.getVolume());
        //dbCollection.insert(document);
        //prop.getProperty("collection").trim()
        dbCollection.getCollection("bars");
        dbCollection.save(document, WriteConcern.NORMAL);
    }
```

Comment: What concurrency issue are you referring to? An issue with the java driver? What "write" are you attempting?

Comment: @Mark Hillick, somehow I am mixed up, I have a method call that works when I do a main method, but doesnt work when I run this in jboss, let me add the method call in the question, initially it was dependencies in jboss, but I provided the module dependencies but am still stuck

Comment: I'm not that familiar with jboss so can't really help you there, sorry :( Your method creates a second MongoDB instance, there should only be one MongoDB instance created.

Answer (score 1):

1>This is probably the problem of different connection , I had the same kind of problem which came because " I was calling the same connectionClass many times " . I fixed it by making the connection class singleton. I used MongoClient class for connection . So I will explain it in words , Get a connection for mongoDb for the first time only , from the second time use the same connection.
I am also new on Mongos, Hope this works .

Answer (score 0):

## 1 the very best thing to  check is

- check the mongodb is running
- check if the username and password is correct
- check if the username you are trying to use to access the database has the right owner or

  must be added like this

  ```
  db.addUser("test","test") ------- this will add the default username and password in which the app uses.
  check if the user is created properly db.system.users.find()   ----- you should see you new user in the returned list
  log out .... db.runCommand({"logout":1})
  use databasename
  db.auth("test","test") //do the authorizxation
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i solved edit the config file: /etc/mongod.conf and do this changes:

```
#port = 27017 -> port = 27017
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 -> #bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

With this, all machines can connect to your mongoDB.

Remember restart mongoDB ("sudo service mongod restart")

After this, i update the last version of driver (2.12.0) and thats works.